# WPF drop-down list for auto generated column in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, drop-down-menu, datagrid, auto-generate

How to make a drop-down list when you click on an element of a specific table column in which you can select an element for this cell? Column is auto generated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You have a table containing multiple dropdownlists which are supposed to set the content of the cell they are in, did i get that right?

Comment: It is completely incomprehensible what you need.
Add details to your question.
How is the DataGrid created, for which list?
What is a dropdown list: ComboBox, ContextMenu, Popup?
In which column do you need to implement this?
It is probably obvious that if this is a fully automatically created column, then nothing in it can be changed.
It is necessary to somehow intervene in this process so that the behavior of the column cells begins to differ from the default.

Answer (score 0):

A Combobox in xaml/wpf is used like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="some Name" SelectionChanged="comboboxChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>The Content of your Combobox</ComboBoxItem>
</Combobox>
```

ComboBoxItems are essentially the dropdown part. You can add as many as you want.

In your back end (c#) you can get the selected Value as soon as the "SelectionChanged"-event is triggered. The code for getting the selected Value can be done multiple ways. Example:

```
private void comboboxChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){
    string comboboxvalue = comboboxname.Text;
    //Then set associated textblock or label
    labelname.Content = comboboxvalue;
}
```

The code above would be static though. Dynamically generating these elements could look like this for instance.
When auto-generating, using an inline function for the event is easy.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    ComboBox comboboxname = new ComboBox();
    comboboxname.SelectionChanged += (ss,ee) { string comboBoxValue = comboboxname.Text; labelname.Content = comboBoxValue;}
}
```

Labelname being the name of the Label you want to set. In that loop you will need to implement a way of giving each box a unique name and getting the name of the associated label in there as well. That you will have to figure out on your own as i do not know how and what exactly is generated and what is static.

You will also need to add your dynamically created combobox to your listpanel or grid or whatever you are using. This works like this:

```
listpanelname.Children.Add(comboboxname);
```

Just add that to the "for" loop.